# MacOs El Capitan throwing an error when I compile using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller, osx-elcapitan

So, I am trying to build a python app using Py installer on MacOS. I am doing this on El Capitan because it will be run on many different Macs which can all run different versions of MacOS, and I need the forward compatibility.

It has compiled on Ventura and Catalina, but I am getting this error on run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_console_script_run())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 194, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 1019, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 944, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/Users/h/Desktop/BeansQR 3.2.spec", line 24, in <module>
    exe = EXE(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 590, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 806, in assemble
    osxutils.remove_signature_from_binary(build_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 364, in remove_signature_from_binary
    raise SystemError(f"codesign command ({cmd_args}) failed with error code {p.returncode}!\noutput: {p.stdout}")
SystemError: codesign command (['codesign', '--remove', '--all-architectures', '/Users/h/Desktop/BeansQR/BeansQR3.2/BeansQR 3.2']) failed with error code 1!
output: /Users/h/Desktop/BeansQR/BeansQR3.2/BeansQR 3.2: invalid or unsupported format for signature
```

Never seen this before so any help would be greatly appreciated. Any more questions and I'll comment / edit the post with an answer.

Comment: I suspect you need to use an older `pycompile` that's compatible with El Capitan.

Comment: I did try this using version 4 as I heard it has been tested to work on ElCapitan (the version I am using), but I couldn't get it to install. I can edit the post with the error message, if you would like?

Comment: Also just realised that you said pycompile when I am using pyinstaller. These are different things right?

Comment: I guess, I'm not really familiar with that stuff. I saw pycompile in the title